# Add value to a column each month in Mysql Data Base

Tags: mysql, sql

is there a way to update automatically the values of a column in a table in Mysql DB with a predifined value and the update should occur each month.

The situation is that i want to update the column balance in the table employees adding 2.5 days each month to each employee and the total amount of days should be reset each two years for each employee.

Comment: Use a programming script in PHP, Python, or other language to do this, not a stored procedure or trigger event. Databases should be abstracted from business logic. They must be agnostic to applications only there to store and secure relational data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using mysql's Create Event strategy that can take away from needing to do cron jobs.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE EVENT monthlyAddFlexDaysEvent
ON SCHEDULE EVERY '1' MONTH
STARTS '2015-09-01 00:00:00'
DO 
BEGIN
 update empAccrued set daysAccrued=daysAccrued+2.5;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

---

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE EVENT annualThingEvent
ON SCHEDULE EVERY '1' YEAR
STARTS '2016-01-01 00:00:00'
DO 
BEGIN
 -- perform some annual thing
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

---

In just about any event you could do something that doesn't fall on say the first of the year. Such as a weekly event that handles updates based on employee anniversary dates.

From the Manual page on [CREATE EVENT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-event.html),

> ```
> interval:
>     quantity {YEAR | QUARTER | MONTH | DAY | HOUR | MINUTE |
>               WEEK | SECOND | YEAR_MONTH | DAY_HOUR | DAY_MINUTE |
>               DAY_SECOND | HOUR_MINUTE | HOUR_SECOND | MINUTE_SECOND
> ```

Properly setting up events to even happen and monitoring them is important.

```
show variables where variable_name='event_scheduler';
+-----------------+-------+
| Variable_name   | Value |
+-----------------+-------+
| event_scheduler | OFF   |
+-----------------+-------+
```

ooops, the event scheduler is not turned on.

Well I can wait all day long, events aren't even turned on

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;  -- turn her on

show variables where variable_name='event_scheduler';
+-----------------+-------+
| Variable_name   | Value |
+-----------------+-------+
| event_scheduler | ON    |
+-----------------+-------+
```

List all events by schema name:

```
show events from so_gibberish;
```

or

```
show events\G; -- <--------- I like this one from mysql> prompt
show events; -- <--------- from workbench / sqlyog


*************************** 1. row ***************************
                  Db: so_gibberish
                Name: set_trips_finished
             Definer: GuySmiley@localhost
           Time zone: SYSTEM
                Type: RECURRING
          Execute at: NULL
      Interval value: 1
      Interval field: MINUTE
              Starts: 2015-08-23 00:00:00
                Ends: NULL
              Status: ENABLED
          Originator: 1
character_set_client: utf8
collation_connection: utf8_general_ci
  Database Collation: utf8_general_ci
```

Comment: @ Drew thanks for the explanation and i want to know what is better, creatin a cron job or using create event, if i turn my app off and i start it like after two months, would the cron update with the values of two months ? i'm really confused

Comment: if you turn what off?  The mysql database is really the issue. Is mysql running, can people connect (including cron), are events turned on or off as in my Answer. When you say app, what does that mean, like a web server? In any case, basically what I said in this little box down here and in the Answer. IMO, anything that you can do inside of the db without involving crontab, is sweet.

Comment: thanks you put me on the right way, i have a clear vision of what i'm gonna do :)

Comment: sounds good. When you find the Answer that works best for you, give it a green check mark. Wait a while, other good answers could be lurking.

Answer (score 3):

Databases don't really work that way.  They are meant for storing information. You can write triggers so if you update a row or insert then an event happens but other then that the data doesn't change

Something like this should be handled in the application logic. Creat a cron or other periodic job that will grab rows created on X date and update them

Comment: is it possible to use Create Event statement ?

Comment: i'll do a research about it and i think it would solve the problem