# Select top ten entries of multiple rows in MySQL

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql, performance

I've got a table which manages user scores, e.g.:

```
    id   scoreA   scoreB    ...   scoreX
------  -------  -------    ...  -------
     1      ...      ...    ...      ...
     2      ...      ...    ...      ...
```

Now i wanted to create a scoreboard which can be sorted by each of the scores (only descending).

However, I can't just query the entries and send them to the client (which renders them with Javascript) as the table contains thousands of entries and sending all of those entries to the client would create unreasonable traffic.

I came to the conclusion that all non-relevant entries (entries which may not show up in the scoreboard as the score is too low) should be discarded on the server-side with the following rule of thumb:

```
If any of the scores is within the top ten for this specific score keep the entry.
If none of the scores is within the top ten for this specific score discard it.
```

Now I ran into the question if this can be done efficiently with (My)SQL or if this processing should take place in the php-code querying the database to keep the whole thing performant.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Wouldn't this just work? `SELECT * FROM scores ORDER BY scoreX DESC LIMIT 10`

Comment: I would have to repeat this for every score - as the processing takes place on the client side. Maybe this could be solved by merging all those result sets - I'll give it a try!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go with rows, not columns, for storing scores. Have composite index on userid,score. A datetime column could also be useful. Consider not having the top 10 snapshot table anyway, just the lookup that you suggest. So an `order by score desc` and `Limit 10` in query.

Not that the below reference is the authority on [Covering Indexes](https://www.percona.com/blog/2006/11/23/covering-index-and-prefix-indexes/), but to throw the term out there for your investigation. Good luck.

Comment: I agree, this would be the preferred method.  Personally I would use a master detail table - but that might be too much work for mewking.

Comment: it's a covering index anyway (perhaps), don't even need data from the datapage. It would be snappy

Comment: no problem. It you do a select * as @DanielSharp mentioned, or went after a third column, then the index would cease to be a covering index, although it it would a useful one. The problem with doing ColumnA ... ColumnX in one row, is that, you need to reshuffle ordering, no ? Plus it is de-normalized, and unnecessary housekeeping

Comment: if you were to use Create Event (see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32291923/1816093) ) and it runs, say, hourly, then one row could be, of course, a fast lookup. Note that on The Stack, for tag statistics, the stats are updated at the end of day

Answer (score 1):

you can try to use INDEX for specific and performance enhances.
This will query specific results for your kind of problem.
Read about it [here](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/high-performance-mysql/0596003064/ch04.html)

good luck, buddy.

Comment: Link is broken - one ] too much :)

Answer (score 0):

I would first fire a query to obtain the top 10.  Then fire the query to get the results, using the top 10 in your sql.

I can't formulate the query until I know what you mean by top 10 - give an example.