# Creating a Timer using php and ajax

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, timer

Could someone assist me in creating a live database timer.

It will have a start time in database, I am using PHP and am hoping to use js or ajax whatever works best for what I am trying to complete.

I've written some pseudo-like code to illustrate how I plan to do this:

```
BEGIN

Request server time
// adjust server time with client time

get serverTime
get clientTime

adjustment = serverTime - clientTime
timeData = timeData - adjustment

THEN 
send timeData to server

END
```

Comment: how about looking into `create event`. It's like Timex. It just keeps running and running and ...  Here is an [example stub](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32291923/1816093)

Comment: note, that is for a server time, unrelated to ajax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div id="time">
    <span id="hour">hh</span>:<span id="min">mm</span>:<span id="sec">ss</span>
</div>

setInterval(update, 1000);
function update() {
  var date = new Date()

  var hours = date.getHours()
  if (hours < 10) hours = '0'+hours
  document.getElementById('hour').innerHTML = hours

  var minutes = date.getMinutes()
  if (minutes < 10) minutes = '0'+minutes
  document.getElementById('min').innerHTML = minutes

  var seconds = date.getSeconds()
  if (seconds < 10) seconds = '0'+seconds
  document.getElementById('sec').innerHTML = seconds
}
```

You don't need to use ajax or php you can do it with simple javascript

Comment: However, if I was to not use a server side language an end user can simply edit their systems time which would greatly affect the application.