# Trigger MSQL big issue, sql not working?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, magento, triggers

I am trying to build a trigger, the problems is it is not working. I have syntax problems. I need to build a trigger which will update a table with another record in the same table before the table has been been updated. The trigger below describes what i want to do but it does not work.

```
$deletequery = '

        DELIMITER //

        CREATE TRIGGER after_insert_job_sent
        AFTER INSERT
           ON Envato_CustomConfig_job_sent FOR EACH ROW

        BEGIN

          DELETE FROM `Envato_CustomConfig_Job_Queue` 
          WHERE Job_ID = '.$value['Job_ID'].'
          AND email -'.$value['email'].';

          UPDATE `envato_customconfig_job_status` SET `email_Sent_Count`= email_Sent_Count+1 
          WHERE Job_ID = '.$value['Job_ID'].'             
        END; //

        DELIMITER;

        insert into Envato_CustomConfig_job_sent
        values ( NULL , '.$value['Job_ID'].', '.$value['email'].', now();   

        ';
```

EDIT:

Why does my query append other records aswell?....
so basically it is working however on the update is add one to the last record the db. i have tried LIMIT it did not work. any ideas.

```
insert into Envato_CustomConfig_job_sent
values ( NULL , '37', 'email', now());

DELETE FROM Envato_CustomConfig_job_queue
WHERE Job_ID = '37'
AND email ='email';

UPDATE envato_customconfig_job_status SET `email_Sent_Count`= email_Sent_Count+1 
WHERE Job_ID = '37';
```

Comment: why are you creating a trigger and a plain jane other stmt outside of it, wrapped all in one string.

Comment: i dont understand. @Drew

Comment: The trigger has to be stored in the db on its own merit, and persist. It isn't done the way you are doing it, with an embedded PHP chunk `WHERE Job_ID = '.$value['Job_ID'].'`

Comment: do i need to create the trigger when im creating the tables? @Drew

Comment: not a bad idea superman

Comment: that is not to say a PHP multi-query is not possible in general, just not like that :) .... if you want to pass a piece of code a parameter, like to a function or a stored proc, then go that route. But triggers are, well, triggered without parameter passing

Answer (score 1):

Triggers, Events, Functions, and Stored Procedures reside as code stored in a particular database. Only some of them have parameter passing (such as Functions and Stored Procedures). Others just fire are their own (Events and Triggers).

What you are attempting to do is perform a `delete` with PHP variable information which is just a query.

At least you have the **DELIMITER** concept nailed down, that stands in the way as a trivial error that catches many people. But if you would have *highlighted* the Trigger block, you would have seen the syntax error highlighting, most likely, around the embedded `WHERE Job_ID = '.$value['Job_ID'].'` chunk. And since the trigger runs on triggered events such as insert, etc, it would have no clue about that chunk.

When I say highlighted, I mean in a program such as Mysql Workbench.

Comment: Nice, you helped clear that up a lot. Just wondering if u have any ideas on my problem in the edit? @drew

Comment: do you have triggers or not at the moment. Plus your 'edit' to bottom of question references 3 tables (sent, queue, and status tables). Remember too that triggers can fire on insert, update, delete, and are **married** to a particular table. And have to be explicity coded as such.  I have no clue what state your db is in with row values, trigger existence. Flying blind

Comment: I think you might want to look into [mysql create event](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32291923/)  when you get a chance. It might be right up your alley for code that fires, say every minute or two, and *does stuff*